# iOS11 Basic Authentication Issue

Tags: authentication, safari, ios11

Since moving to iOS11 Safari is re-asking for a users credentials for our server after it has been to payment site SagePay.
I wonder if anyone else is seeing this issue and has a fix/work around?

This is the series of events;
1. User logs on to our https server using Basic Authentication.
2. User is forwarded to SagePay to take a credit card payment.
3. User is forwarded back to our server with payment success/failure etc.  -  at this point Safari in iOS11 prompts for the username/password on our site again.

In iOS10 the user isn't prompted for their credentials again, the browser just goes back to our site as normal.

Any info on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

OK I have found the cause so am reporting this in case it's useful for others.
In iOS 11 Safari has a new setting for 'Prevent Cross-Site Tracking' which is switched on by default - if this is switched off the return to our website works OK and the user isn't asked for their credentials again.